# How to input a 1-D array of dimensions into numpy.random.randn?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, random

Say I have a 1-D array `dims`:

```
dims = np.array((1,2,3,4))
```

I want to create a n-th order normally distributed tensor where n is the size of the `dims` and `dims[i]` is the size of the i-th dimension.

I tried to do

```
A = np.random.randn(dims)
```

But this doesn't work. I could do

```
A = np.random.randn(1,2,3,4)
```

which would work but `n` can be large and `n` can be random in itself. How can I read in a array of the size of the dimensions in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Use unpacking with an asterisk:

```
np.random.randn(*dims)
```

Answer (score 1):

Unpacking is standard Python when the signature is `randn(d0, d1, ..., dn)`

```
In [174]: A = np.random.randn(*dims)
In [175]: A.shape
Out[175]: (1, 2, 3, 4)
```

`randn` docs suggests `standard_normal` which takes a tuple (or array which can be treated as a tuple):

```
In [176]: B = np.random.standard_normal(dims)
In [177]: B.shape
Out[177]: (1, 2, 3, 4)
```

In fact the docs, say new code should use this:

```
In [180]: rgn = np.random.default_rng()
In [181]: rgn.randn
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-181-b8e8c46209d0>", line 1, in <module>
    rgn.randn
AttributeError: 'numpy.random._generator.Generator' object has no attribute 'randn'

In [182]: rgn.standard_normal(dims).shape
Out[182]: (1, 2, 3, 4)
```